# INSERT INTO table (user_2) VALUES (?) WHERE user_1 IS NOT NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

After post request i need to:

1. Check if u_1 exists on table and if it is in table insert u_2 where u_1 in not null
2. If u_1 is not exists insert u_1

Here is my **PHP** code

```
if ( isset( $_POST["cards"],$_POST["user"],$_POST["cardvalues"],$_POST["tablekey"] ) ) {

    $cards = $_POST["cards"];
    $user = $_POST["user"];
    $cardvalues = $_POST["cardvalues"];
    $tablekey = $_POST["tablekey"];

    $checkIfNull = "SELECT u_1 FROM tables";
    $insertIntoU_2 = "INSERT INTO tables (u_2) VALUES (?) WHERE u_1 IS NOT NULL";
    $insertIntoU_1 = "INSERT INTO tables (u_1,all_cards,card_value,table_key) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($checkIfNull)) {
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($insertIntoU_2)) {
                    $stmt->bind_param("s",$user);
                    if ($stmt->execute()) {
                        echo "user 2 is in table";
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($insertIntoU_1)) {
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$user,$cards,$cardvalues,$tablekey);
                    if ($stmt->execute()) {
                        echo "user 1 is in table";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `INSERT .. VALUES` does not allow WHERE clause. Use `INSERT .. SELECT` instead. PS. What `u_1` do you try to check, from what row?

Comment: @Akina i need to insert u_2 inside row where u_1 is not empty and if u_1 is empty just insert u_1 as new row

Comment: *i need to insert u_2 inside row where u_1 is not empty* How some column in a row may be "not empty" if you're just going to insert this row? maybe you mean that **the other row** with this value in this column already exists in a table?

Comment: I just need if u_1 is not empty insert u_2 like in this [image](https://i.imgur.com/isCqPZj.png) and if u_1 is EMPTY just insert u_1 like in [image](https://i.imgur.com/BqvOj2v.png)

Comment: *I just need if u_1 is not empty* WHERE it must be not empty? In what row? Does your task is: If a row with specified `u_1` value not exists then insert it with empty `u_2` else update this row and set its `u_2` with specified value? Anycase show (add into question text) `tables` CREATE TABLE script (as formatted text, not as image).

Comment: Imagine user clicks on start button and sending post requests after click php should check if somewhere u_1 is not empty and insert u_2 inside that not empty u_1 row and if u_1 is empty  should create new row with new table id and insert data inside u_1

Comment: Well, more clear... but what if u_1 exists, and u_2 in this row is not empty? overwrite? *php should check if somewhere u_1 is not empty* with ANY value? or with some specific value?

Comment: No. just pass and find row were u_1 is not empty and u_2 is empty or create new row and insert u_1

Comment: I.e. you have some value XXX. If the row with non-empty u_1 and empty u_2 exists then set this value XXX to u_2. If the row with non-empty u_1 and empty u_2 not exists then insert new row and set this value XXX to u_1. Is it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed sql syntax and now it works as i expected.

```
if ( isset( $_POST["cards"],$_POST["user"],$_POST["cardvalues"],$_POST["tablekey"] ) ) {
    
        $user = $_POST["user"];
        $cards = $_POST["cards"];
        $cardvalues = $_POST["cardvalues"];
        $tablekey = $_POST["tablekey"];
    
        $checkIfNull = "SELECT table_id FROM tables WHERE u_1 IS NOT NULL AND u_2 = '' LIMIT 1";
        $insertIntoU_2 = "UPDATE tables SET u_2 = ? WHERE table_id = ?";
        $insertIntoU_1 = "INSERT INTO tables (u_1,all_cards,card_value,table_key) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    
        if ( $stmt = $conn->prepare( $checkIfNull ) ) {
            if ( $stmt->execute() ) {
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                $tableIdArray = array();
                $i = 0;
                if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
                    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
                        $tableIdArray["table_id"][$i] = $row["table_id"];
                        $i++;
                    } 
                    $tableID = $tableIdArray["table_id"][0];
                    if ( $stmt = $conn->prepare( $insertIntoU_2 ) ) {
                        $stmt->bind_param( "ss",$user,$tableID );
                        $stmt->execute();
                    }
                } else {
                    if ( $stmt = $conn->prepare( $insertIntoU_1 ) ) {
                        $stmt->bind_param( "ssss",$user,$cards,$cardvalues,$tablekey );
                        $stmt->execute();
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_value_into ( value_to_insert INT ) -- or maybe TEXT ? set proper datatype
BEGIN
IF EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
            FROM tables
            WHERE u_2 IS NULL ) THEN
    UPDATE test
    SET u_2 = value_to_insert
    WHERE u_2 IS NULL;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO tables
    SET u_1 = value_to_insert;
END IF;
END
```

and then simply (do not forget to add needed error checkings)

```php
$sql = "CALL insert_value_into (?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$user);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: thanks for your time but i wrote code that not changing my code sturcture too much.